# Using texlive, why can I compile knitr Rnw file to pdf from R but not the tex ouput from knit R to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

knitr compiles and produces pdf file but the tex file that is produced by knitr does not compile (with livetex)

Here is test.Rnw

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\title{y}
\author{z}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
<<assignment, echo = TRUE>>=
(X <- 10)
@
\end{document}
```

The following produces pdf file:  `texi2pdf(file = "test.tex", clean = TRUE)`

The reamble that is produced by knitr has a problem:

```
  \usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother
```

Here are the errors:

```
    \begin{minipage} does not have matching end; at least one unbalanced
 begin-end  test.tex    /tests-R    line 39 Problem

\end{minipage} found with no preceding \begin   test.tex    /tests-R    line 38
```

For obvious reasons, at least one publisher wants the tex document, not the Rnw document

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on my machine. Whats livetex?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my machine either. Ubuntu 13.10 + TeXLive 2013.

Comment: ditto Ubuntu 12.04 TeXLive 2009

Comment: Works fine for me too: OSX 10.8.5 + TeXLive 2013

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but it seems to be a path issue. If `yourfile.Rnw` is on a path with spaces, `knit2pdf` will throw an error and you can see it clearly in `texput.log` not `yourfile.log` as the error message states.  However if you compile the `yourfile.tex` by hand, everything seems to be okay.

Perhaps @Yihui can shed some light on why this might be the case.

**EDIT** Here's a log of the output:

```
knit2pdf("test.Rnw")


processing file: test.Rnw
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: assignment (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi TRUE

  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: test.tex

Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'test.tex' failed.
Messages:
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting.
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: see test.log for errors.
```

`test.log` doesn't exist in the working directory; `texput.log` does and contains this message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.7.13)  24 JUL 2014 10:04
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\nonstopmode \input /Users/james/Documents/stack exchange/test.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> ...opmode \input /Users/james/Documents/stack 
                                                  exchange/test.tex
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the problem with test.Rnw under a directory that contains spaces. Are you using Windows? Is your LaTeX distribution also TeXLive?

Comment: This is on a Mac, R 3.1.0, knitr 1.6, using TeXLive (MacTeX).  I've edited the response above with a log of the output.

Comment: Hmm... I think you are right: the space in the file path does seem to be a problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Yihui So is there a way to avoid this error when there is a space in the file path?

Comment: @BerkU. Sorry I don't know. I do not use Mac OS X very often.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't receive an error. Used the "Compile PDF" button from RStudio, which created following *.tex-file, which I can compile using TexMaker:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
\linewidth
\else
\Gin@nat@width
\fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
\def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
\ifinner\ifhmode%
\def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
\fi\fi%
\def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
\colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
 % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
 \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
\@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
\@setminipage}}%
{\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
\at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\title{y}
\author{z}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{(X} \hlkwb{<-} \hlnum{10}\hlstd{)}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] 10
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}

\end{document}
```